# Pandas Replace All Substrings in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'A':['^|^^|^','abc'],'B':['def','^|^']})

d
        A    B
0  ^|^^|^  def
1     abc  ^|^
```

I need to replace all instances of "^|^" with blank spaces (" ").

The desired result is:

```
        A    B
0           def
1     abc
```

I've tried these, but to no avail:

```
d.replace('^|^',' ') #(replaces nothing)
d.replace('^|^',' ',regex=True) #(only works for the value in column B, second row)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to escape special RegEx symbols:

```
import re

In [191]: d.replace(re.escape('^|^'),' ', regex=True)
Out[191]:
     A    B
0       def
1  abc
```

Comment: Is re a method of a library?

Comment: @DanceParty2, it's a module (library)

Comment: @DanceParty2 Or you could escape it yourself `d.replace('\^\|\^',' ',regex=True)`

Comment: @piRSquared, yeah, thank you! Just wanted to be bit more dynamic... ;-)

Comment: I didn't know about `re.escape`.  That looks cleaner to me.  I just wanted to offer something that @DanceParty2 could use to better understand... possibly.  Great answer (-: just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks! I am so fortunate to have such great help.